# Updating javascript cookie value, without deleting previous value

Tags: javascript, cookies

Having a bit of trouble with JavaScript Cookies. I'm making a to-do-list that lasts until midnight. I've got my cookie set to expire and when I add items to do they all get stored into the cookie value all fine and dandy.

If i reload the page they're all still in the value which is great. **BUT**, if I go to add another item after reloading the page it gets rd of the previous items and starts again.

I'm basically looking for a way to have new items added to the end of the cookie value, instead of it deleting what's already there and starting fresh.

The app can be found at [todo.lukeseager.com](http://todo.lukeseager.com)

The cookie function is as follows:

```
function midnightCookie(name,value,path) {
    var expires = "";
    var date = new Date();
    var midnight = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 23, 59, 59);
    expires = "; expires=" + midnight.toGMTString();
    if (!path) {
        path = "/";
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=" + path;
}
```

And to store the information put into the to-do list I use this:

```
var todoUserList = window.todoTable.innerHTML = window.todoTable.innerHTML +
    "<tr class='list-row'><td class='small-column'>"+todoStatus+"</td>"+
    "<td>"+todoTitle+"<br><span class='description'>"+todoDescription+"</span></td>"+
    "<td class='small-column'>"+todoUrgent+"</td></tr>";

    window.midnightCookie("todo",todoUserList);
```

If there's anything else needed please let me know :) All the files can ofc be accessed through dev tools if that's easier for you :)

Comment: localStorage is probably a better solution for this. just a side note.

Comment: Why save all that markup (and not the variable-value pairs) in the cookie itself?

Comment: Would you save each variable individually? Status/Title/Desc/Urgency. I'm struggling to understand how they would be outputted together if  store them individually?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.cookie += ";" + name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=" + path;
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work. Now I the Cookie doesn't seem to be saving at all, can't seem to get it back to how it was previously :/